# how to use useSelector() in multiple dispatch()

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, dispatch

I am trying to display the length of the `student` and `teacher` from the store's state. but why is it that when using multiple dispatch(), it is overlapping to the previous dispatch() hence, displaying a wrong length.

in the parent component I used multiple `dispatch()`

```
const dispatch = useDispatch()

    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(getStudents());
      dispatch(getTeachers());
      dispatch(getSections());
    }, [dispatch])
```

in the `<StudentInfo/>`, I tried to access the state and display it.

```
export default function StudentInfo() {
    const students = useSelector((state) => state.students);

    //try
    const studentsRef = React.useRef(students);

    useEffect(() => {
        studentsRef.current = students;
    }, [students])

    return(
        <>
        <Box style={{ paddingTop: '1.5rem', height: '2rem'}}>
            <SchoolSharpIcon sx={{fontSize: '40px'}} />
        </Box>
        <Box style={{fontSize: '1rem'}}>
            Number of Students enrolled: {studentsRef.current.length}
        </Box>
        </>
    )
}
```

same way in `<TeacherInfo/>`

```
export default function TeacherInfo() {

    const teachers = useSelector((state) => state.teachers);

    //try
    const teachersRef = React.useRef(teachers);

    useEffect(() => {
        teachersRef.current = teachers;
    }, [teachers])

    return(
        <>
        <Box style={{ paddingTop: '1.5rem', height: '2rem'}}>
            <AccountBoxSharpIcon sx={{fontSize: '40px'}} />
        </Box>
        <Box style={{fontSize: '1rem'}}>
            Number of Teachers: {teachersRef.current.length}
        </Box>
        </>
    )
}
```

it's displaying the wrong length. for example, the `<StudentInfo/>` is displaying the length of the `teacher` state and vice versa

```
export function students (students = [], action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_ALL':
        console.log(action.payload)
        console.log("students?")
        return action.payload;
    case 'CREATE':
        return [...students, action.payload];


    default:
        return students;
}
```

}

```
export function teachers (teachers = [], action) {
switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_ALL':
        console.log(action.payload)
        console.log("teachers?")
        return action.payload;
    case 'CREATE':
        return [...teachers, action.payload];


    default:
        return teachers;
}
```

}

Comment: You have to show your store code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same action types for actions in different reducer. This means that when you load/create `teachers`, you update `students` as well, and vice versa.

Use different types for similar actions that appear in multiple reducers. Update the action types in the action creators, and the reducers as well:

```
export function students (students = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'students/FETCH_ALL':
    ...
    case 'students/CREATE':
    ...
    default:
        return students;
}

export function teachers (teachers = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'teachers/FETCH_ALL':
    ...
    case 'teachers/CREATE':
    ...

    default:
        return teachers;
}
```

In additon, the `useEffect` block is executed after the JSX have been rendered, and only then the ref is updated. Updating the ref doesn't cause a re-render, so you always might have the previous ref's value. You don't need a ref (and the `useEffect`), just the value you get from the selector, for example:

```
Number of Students enrolled: {students.length}

Number of Teachers: {teachers.length}
```

Comment: it still displays the same data even though I am accessing different store state

Comment: The problem is the actions' types. See updated answer.